# Duplicate week trips row x the value of each column

Tags: r

I'm trying to duplicate a row of trips per day of the week times the amount of each day.

Example:

| M | T | W | TH | F | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

In this example the result would be:

| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I've tried implementing this code:

```
duplicate_accordingto_value <- function(row) {
  sum_cols <- sum(row[15:21] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  if (sum_cols == 0) {

    duplicated_obs <- row
    duplicated_observation[15:21] <- 1
    return(rbind(row, duplicated_observation))
  } else {
    duplicated_observations <- list()
    indices <- which(row[15:21] > 0)
    
    for (i in 1:sum_cols) {
      new_observation <- row
      new_observation[15:21] <- 0
      if (i <= length(indexes)) {
        new_observation[15 + indices[i] - 1] <- 1
      }
      duplicated_observations[[i]] <- new_observation
    }
    
    return(do.call(rbind, duplicated_observations))
  }
}

# Apply the function to all the rows
sfu2 <- sfu2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do({
    observation <- as.data.frame(.)
    duplicate_accordingto_value(observation)
  }) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But in some rows the duplication outputs a row full of zeros, the amount of duplications is right, but the duplication itself is wrong and I can't quite figure it out

Edit:
Yeah so as Mark said in the comments, the sample data is a lot shorter than the actual data and also the complete data is a dataset, idk if that affects a lot with the way the code is managed, here's an example of a full row of the dataset

[image: Here's a sample info of the dataset im working on]

For the time being i just want to deal with the columns of the days of the week (15:21) but the full rows are the ones being duplicated based on the values of those columns as I stated at the top

Comment: Hey David! I realise I wrote an answer to your question without actually diagnosing what is wrong with your code. If you could include some sample data that would be great! Your data references row[15:21], but your example is obviously much shorter

Comment: Yeah i've updated the post with a sample of the data and hopefully a better explanation of what im trying to solve

Comment: ah thanks! I wasn't sure if there was some extra important information we were missing. It's good that it's just a subset

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
x <- c("M" = 0, "T" = 2, "W" = 1, "TH" = 0, "F" = 1, "Sat" = 2, "Sun" = 0)

# create a diagonal matrix
a = diag(length(x))

purrr::imap(seq_len(nrow(a)), ~ rep(a[.x,], x[.y])) |>
  unlist() |>
    matrix(ncol = ncol(a), byrow = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below (borrow `x` from [@Mark's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77350432/12158757))

```
m <- matrix(0, sum(x), length(x))
idx <- rep(seq_along(x), x)
m[cbind(seq_along(idx), idx)] <- 1
```

and you will obtain

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
d <- data.frame("M" = 0, "T" = 2, "W" = 1, "TH" = 0, "F" = 1, "Sat" = 2, "Sun" = 0)

l <- lapply(1:7, function(i) {
      count <- sum(d[,i])
      v <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
      v[i] <- 1
      
      return(t(replicate(count, v)))
      
    })

res <- do.call(rbind, l[unlist(lapply(l, function(m) ncol(m) > 0))])
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple rows of weeks:

```
library(matrixStats)

f <- function(x) {
  m <- length(x)
  n <- ncol(x)
  x0 <- rowCumsums(cbind(0L, x[,-n]))
  x2 <- rowSums(x) - x - x0
  matrix(
    rep(rep(c(0L, 1L, 0L), m), matrix(c(x0, x, x2), 3, m, 1)),
    ncol = n,
    dimnames = dimnames(x)
  )
}
```

Demonstrating with three weeks:

```
set.seed(1037011516)
m <- 3L
x <- matrix(sample(0:3, 7*m, 1), m, 7, 0,
            list(NULL, c("M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "Sat", "Sun")))
x
#>      M T W TH F Sat Sun
#> [1,] 2 0 3  0 2   0   0
#> [2,] 0 1 0  0 1   0   1
#> [3,] 2 1 0  0 2   1   0
f(x)
#>       M T W TH F Sat Sun
#>  [1,] 1 0 0  0 0   0   0
#>  [2,] 1 0 0  0 0   0   0
#>  [3,] 0 0 1  0 0   0   0
#>  [4,] 0 0 1  0 0   0   0
#>  [5,] 0 0 1  0 0   0   0
#>  [6,] 0 0 0  0 1   0   0
#>  [7,] 0 0 0  0 1   0   0
#>  [8,] 0 1 0  0 0   0   0
#>  [9,] 0 0 0  0 1   0   0
#> [10,] 0 0 0  0 0   0   1
#> [11,] 1 0 0  0 0   0   0
#> [12,] 1 0 0  0 0   0   0
#> [13,] 0 1 0  0 0   0   0
#> [14,] 0 0 0  0 1   0   0
#> [15,] 0 0 0  0 1   0   0
#> [16,] 0 0 0  0 0   1   0
```